# As of 2018 how much of a performance advantage is gained inlining functions

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, compiler-optimization, jit

Given the current state of compilers, is it still beneficial to performance to favour inlining code instead of splitting it into multiple functions.

For example is the following necessarily going to be faster if inlined.

```
const a = (x) => {
  b(c(d(x)))
}
```

Note: I'm looking for a general heuristic. I'm well aware that the contents of the functions in the above example will make a difference, as will the compiler, but I'm interested in whether a general rule of thumb exists. If it makes a difference I am particularly interested in performance in a function passed to `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: ... Why title-case?

Comment: @user202729 corrected.